# Django: grab current GET parameters in url and modify one (or many) of them

Tags: django, url, get, parameters

Suppose i have an url like

```
www.mysite.com/?param_1=val_1&param_2=val_2
```

and in my template, i have a list of link corresponding to those parameters.

How can i grab this url and add or modify the parameters, so i don't have to submit the get request everytime, but just pass the new url?

Example:

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/?param_1=val_1&param_2=val_2_modified">val_2_modified</a>
<a href="www.mysite.com/?param_1=val_1&param_2=val_2&param_3=new_val">new_val</a>
```

and so on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py#L152

```
from django.utils.http import urlencode

def get_query_string(params, new_params=None, remove=None):
    if new_params is None: new_params = {}
    if remove is None: remove = []
    p = params.copy()
    for r in remove:
        for k in p.keys():
            if k.startswith(r):
                del p[k]
    for k, v in new_params.items():
        if v is None:
            if k in p:
                del p[k]
        else:
            p[k] = v
    return '?%s' % urlencode(p)

# get_query_string(dict(request.GET.items()), {'param_2': 'val_2_modified', 'param_3': 'new_val'})
```

To use this in templates just write template tag (I already forgot how to write template tags for django).

Comment: i'm trying this :) thanks :) also for templates: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/553/ i just found out this, and seems perfect!